# Can I play with more than 1 player in Dungeon Defenders (demo)?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I just picked up the PC [Dungeon Defenders](http://dungeondefenders.com/) demo (aka "Dungeon Defense" - I think they are changing the name for he full release). I quite enjoyed playing it single player with my XBox 360 controller.

The preview movies and tutorial text reference a 2-4 player split-screen mode. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to set it up. When I got to the player select screen, it seemed like I *should* be able to add a second player, but I could not figure out how.

I have 1 XBox 360 controller and mouse/keyboard. Can I play with more than 1 person, and if so how do I do it?

Comment: I was about to post the same question

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that the demo does not support multiplayer (but the full game will).

> There's also support planned for four player multiplayer via online and LAN.

[Source](http://news.bigdownload.com/2010/08/25/udk-demo-dungeon-defense-to-morph-into-full-game-dungeon-defende/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the Demo, but in the full game, **Yes**, you can play with more than one player. If you have a keyboard & mouse and an Xbox controller, connect them both to the pc then when you start the game hit the "play Local" button in the starting game menu. Then press the "click to join" button with the mouse first. Then press "start" button on the Xbox controller, then the 2nd player can join in.

Of course you have to create at least 2 heroes to play!

The game will auto manage split-screen but you can configure it yourself from the option screen to either horizontal or vertical according to your preference.